# Implementing Antivirus on file upload using J2EE application?

Tags: enterprise, antivirus, symantec

Please provide information on how to integrate Symantec antivirus or any other enterprise antivirus using Java API with Java web application. On uploading files, we need to scan for virus and the result needs to be displayed as (Passed/Failed) to the user.

Regards
RamC

Answer (score 0):

As a start, I recommend you to check this (rather old) post, using Symantec Scan Engine.
How to use Symantec Scan Engine 5.2 content scanning technologies for direct integration with your applications or devices:
http://www.symantec.com/connect/articles/how-use-symantec-scan-engine-52-content-scanning-technologies-direct-integration-your-appli

Answer (score 0):

Metascan would work for your requirements as it allows for API integration of Symantec as well as many other antivirus products. There is java sample code available as well to assist with your project. Product details: http://www.opswat.com/products/metascan  |  Technical documentation and sample code https://portal.opswat.com/ (requires registration for a free account).

*** /// Disclaimer: I am an employee at OPSWAT, who makes the Metascan product ***